# Verb suggestion needed with meanings of to embody, to characterize, to make you realize, to make you experience an epiphany etc

Tags: single-word-requests

"...Scenes of meadows, hills, on which you play for all day until the sun above sets. These scenes (some verb) the great beauty and peace found in nature..."

The meaning I want to give is that those scenes embody, depict the great beauty of nature and thus make you strikingly notice the wonders of nature, kind of an epiphany. I thought of to depict or to portray but these verbs do not have a really strong effect. To symbolize or to characterize do not really work well either. I looked up the words in thesauri but alas, I could not find a verb that would perfectly fit. So in short, what verb do you think would fit here (or should use a verb and an adverb)?

Comment: a single verb, maybe "ingrain"

Answer (score 2):

Epitomise - "to be a perfect example of" (Oxford Dictionaries)
I’m British, you may prefer "epitomize".

OED definition of Epitomize:
"To make an epitome of; to abridge."

OED definition of Epitome:
"A person who or thing which is a perfect embodiment of a particular quality or type. Usually in the (very) epitome of."

Comment: Spot on, Pam, but please add a supporting reference.

Comment: Edited to add some references @EdwinAshworth. Is OED a suitable reference? It’s reputable but not "open source" (local libraries subscribe here in the UK).

Comment: OED is obviously authoritative, but I'm never sure about legal issues. ODO often works just as well, and can be linked to. I usually head for 'theFreeDictionary' first as there are various good dictionaries grouped there. Sometimes, they outperform OED in certain respects.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth. I agree OED can sound very formal. I hadn't heard of theFreeDictionary. I often check Thesaurus.com, too, for alternatives (but I'm yet to find a perfectly satisfactory alternative word in there!).

Comment: 'TheFreeDictionary' is just a blanket term; cite whichever dictionary you quote there (AHD and/or Collins and/or RHK Webster's ...). ODO and CED can be very useful too (examples and even lists of senses often differ helpfully), as can M-W and Macmillan (which I think labels count usages of nouns).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. To epitomize perfectly fits there. I will use this word. But I must ask, what would be an English verb (or so phrase) with the meanings of making you strikingly realize or making you experience an epiphany? It seems to me that to epitomize does not mean this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**illuminate**  [oxford dict](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/illuminate)

> "...Scenes of meadows, hills, on which you play for all day until the
>   sun above sets. These scenes **illuminate** the great beauty and peace
>   found in nature..."

SYNONYMS (same citation)

light, light up, throw light on, cast light upon, brighten, make brighter, shine on, flood with light, floodlight, irradiate